# Applet web app interaction

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, applet, partial

I have an applet that calls a URL, on a user action, and passes some parameters.  These parameters are executed on a ROR server and then I update a partial, which is on the applet's page, based on the result.  However, the partial is not updating.

The console says that the partial is rendered but it is not.  Is it because I am calling the URL from the applet and the server is unaware that the applet is in the current session, hence it does not know which session partial to render?

Here is the code of the controller:

```
def add_point
 @comments = Comment.find(:all)
 render :update do |page|
  page[:comment_text].value = ""
  page.replace_html :comments_partial, :partial => 'comments', :collections=>@comments
 end
end
```

EDIT: I use Apache commons http wrapper to send the request:

```
 PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:3001/vizs/add_point");

 post.addParameter("upload[test]", dataImg);
 post.addParameter("upload[user_id]", new Integer(user_id).toString());
 post.addParameter("upload[viz_id]", new Integer(viz_id).toString());
```

I think I need to set additional request variables but I am unsure what to set....

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Slotishtype

Answer (score 0):

rails is not aware about the applet, and does not know how to work with it, you need to send xml or json or even html:

```
def add_point
 @comments = Comment.find(:all)
 render :partial => 'comments', :collections=>@comments, :layout => nil
end
```

parse it in applet and fill appropriate fields by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I need to set a request variable in the applet but I am unsure what to set.  I use apache commons http to wrap the request (see updated question).  Do you know what I have to set?

Comment: please update your question so the code of rails part is formated better - it's hard to see whats going on there without formating

Comment: I updated it, all it does is find all comments and update the partial.  However, rails is unsure of where the request is coming from...and I am unsure of how to tell it...I thin I have to call a request and then use that to develop a response...

Comment: try my updated solution, you need to update target page manually